# Serializing a @Validated class

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

Let's say I've got a properties class that's being used in a `Class` that needs to be serialized by Spring Cache, using Redis as the implementation. I'm also validating this class by using Spring's `@Validated` ([docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html)) annotation.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myprops")
@Validated
public class MyProps implements Serializable {

}

@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProps.class)
@Named
public class ClassThatNeedsToBeSerialized implements Serializable {
   @Inject
   private MyProps myProps;
}
```

Attempting to cache an instance of this class:

```
@Inject
private ClassThatNeedsToBeSerialized classThatNeedsToBeSerialized;

@Cacheable("my-cache")
public ClassThatNeedsToBeSerialized fetch() {
   return classThatNeedsToBeSerialized;
}
```

Will throw an exception with the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35)
        at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:94)
        ... 31 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationInterceptor
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:46)
        at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63)
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Is there any way to serialize a class that's annotated with `@Validated`? If not, is there a similar alternative to this that will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed this by registering a `configurationPropertiesValidator` bean as explained [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.0.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-property-validation/src/main/java/sample/propertyvalidation):

Create a custom Validator for `MyClass`:

```
public class ClassThatNeedsToBeSerializedValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return ClassThatNeedsToBeSerialized.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        //Validate
    }
}
```

Register it as a bean:

```
    @Bean
    public Validator configurationPropertiesValidator() {
        return new ClassThatNeedsToBeSerializedValidator();
    }
```

`ClassThatNeedsToBeSerialized` can now implement `Serializable` and be serialized without issues. The downsides of this are:

- No way to register multiple configurationPropertiesValidators as far as I know
- No annotations